# How to randomly shuffle the depth, height,width of 5D matrix?

Tags: python

I have a 5D matrix as `B x C x D x H x W` where D is depth, H is height and W is width. For example, the matrix has size of `16 x 3 x 256 x 128 x 64`, I want to randomly shuffle the last three dimensions (`D,H,W`) to obtain a new matrix. How can I do it in python? The output matrix likes

```
16 x 3 x 256 x 128 x 64
16 x 3 x 64x 128 x 256
16 x 3 x 256 x 64x 128
16 x 3 x 128x 64x 256
...
```

Comment: Can you show us your current code (without shuffling)?

Comment: I just have input of the 5D matrix.

Answer (score 1):

This will transpose your last three axes, assuming you have 5 axes.

```
new_ix = list(np.random.permutation([2, 3, 4]))
np.transpose(x, [0, 1] + new_ix)
```